# Cancel firebase upload if its not finished after some seconds

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I upload an int to the firebase. If the upload is not finished after the first try, a short time (some seconds) it should cancel the upload.

Right now it is the case, that when you upload the value, but you have no internet connection it waits until connections works again and upload the value than. This can be after 30 minutes for example.

The problem is that this uploaded value is already outdated for my purpose. 
I need to cancel the upload if it is not finished after the first try. How can I do that?

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Survey").child("Solution1").child("Result");
mDatabase.setValue(i1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug said, there is no way to cancel a specific write once it's been queued.

There are two ways I can think of to implement (or at least approximate) your use-case:

1. Detect whether the client is connected to the Firebase backend before queueing the write. You'd use an additional listener to the `.info/connected` node for that as shown in the documentation on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state). Just have a top-level listener to that, and then check what the latest value was before you call `setValue()`.
2. You can purge all pending writes by calling [`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().purgeOutstandingWrites()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#purgeOutstandingWrites()). So you could call that before calling `setValue()`.

Alternatively: consider just letting the multiple writes pass through. The server will usually process them in quick succession, and may not even send the outdated ones out to clients.

Comment: Thanks, the first way works fine for me. Simple but effectively.

Comment: Two great ideas that both fit exactly into my use case! This answer deserved more upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

You can't cancel a write to Realtime Database.  What you can do instead is simply re-write the prior value into the same location.  If you don't know the prior value, you're kind of stuck, and you have to accept that the value you wrote will be eventually synchronized.

You could perhaps try to undo the write later in a Cloud Functions trigger, but you will have to figure out at what point that value is out of date, using only information provided to the trigger.